# How to fix z-index on this page?

Tags: css, z-index

I have a page that I have placed a circular image of people (I have highlighted it in red here)
https://nesters.com.au/5852-2/

The image should be at the front but the z-index (or whatever) is causing it to appear behind the above row. It should be in front.
It should look like this:

[image]
Please can you help resolve this? I have read other forums on this and cannot solve the problem.
Tania

Comment: Just add `overflow: visible` to one of the classes on your container with the id of `launch3` it's not a z-index issue, it's an overflow issue since the `circle-image` class is positioned with a negative margin outside the parent's bounds.

Comment: You are an absolute star - thank you so much JHeth

Comment: @Tania isn't my answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `#launch3` tag, one of the containers of your `img` is clipping your `img`, to avoid that you need to add this, to one of your css:

```
#launch3{

   overflow: visible;

}
```